# Proof that $S^1$ isn't homeomorphic to $[0, 1]$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

> Prove that $S^1$ isn't homeomorphic to $[0, 1]$

So when I tried to prove this, I tried looking at topological properties that $S^1$ had but $[0, 1]$ didn't because trying to prove it by contradiction seemed a lot harder, and I'm not sure how I could prove it directly.

The only topological properties that $S^1$ has that I can think of that $[0,1]$ doesn't have is the fact that $S^1$ is a topological manifold without boundary and $[0, 1]$ is a topological manifold with boundary, that being the set $\{0, 1\}$ so if we assume they're homeomorphic we'd arrive at a contradiction since a topological manifold with boundary can't be homeomorphic to a topological manifold without boundary.

But that seems a bit overpowered to use topological manifold theory to prove this somewhat elementary problem. Does anyone know a more elementary proof?

Comment: $[0,1]$ has a *cut point*. That's a point which, if you remove it, leaves the remainder disconnected. Any point you remove from $S^1$ leaves the circle connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any $z\in S^1$. Then $S^1\setminus\{z\}$ is connected, while this property does not hold for $[0,1]$ unless we remove the boundary points.

Comment: In fact this shows there can't be any continuous surjection from $S^1$ to $[0, 1]$

Comment: @Perturbative Actually there is a continuous surjection from $S^1$ to $[0,1]$: $z=x+i y \mapsto \frac{x+1}{2}$.

Comment: @ChoF But suppose there was a continuous surjection $f : S^1 \to [0, 1]$, then pick a point $p \in [0, 1] \setminus \{0, 1\}$, by surjectivity we have $f(x) = p$ for some $x \in S^1$, then we have the restriction of $f$ to $S^1 \setminus \{x\}$ continuous and morover we have $S^1 \setminus \{x\}$ to be path connected, but $f[S^1 \setminus \{x\}] = [0, 1] \setminus \{p\}$ to not be path connected which is a contradiction since the continuous image of a path connected space must be path connected. $\square$. Am I making an error in my argument?

Comment: @Perturbative To make the argument simple, let me consider $[-1,1]$ instead of $[0,1]$. Define $f\colon S^1\to [-1,1]$ by $f(z)=\mathrm{re}(x)$, the real part of $z$. Trivially $f$ is continuous and surjective. Now choose $p=0\in[-1,1]$. Then there are two points $z=\pm i\in S^1$ such that $f(z)=0$. Choose $x=i\in S^1$ as your argument. Then $f(S^1\setminus\{x\})=[-1,1]$ because $f(-i)=0$ covers the missing point $0$.

Comment: @Perturbative. $S^1$ can be defined as $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: x^2+y^2=1\}.$ The projection of points in $\Bbb R^2$  to their first co-ordinates is continuous, and  maps $S^1$ onto  $[-1,1],$ which is homeomorphic to [$0,1].$ ( as in the comments by Chof 8.)

Answer (score 2):

No neighborhood of $0$ in $[0,1]$ is homeorphic to $\mathbb R$. However, every point of $S^1$ has some neighborhood homeorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Nice. But how briefly can you prove that no nbhd of $0$ in $[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: @ Since $\mathbb R$ is connected, such a neighborhood would have to be connected. Therefore, it's an interval. But no interval $[0,a)$ or $[0,a]$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ (they remain connected if we remove $0$ from them).

Comment: I think in your A you meant to say that no $connected$ nbhd of  $0$...(etc.)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet No, I did not. Why? If such a neighborhood is not connected then *of course* it is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I accede to your point/